# Aura:if displays both options

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, conditional, aura-if

I have a problem with aura if in lightning component, the condition doesn't work, my code below :

```
 <aura:if  isTrue="{!v.account.cel_email_mailable__c != 'N' }">
    <div  onclick="{!c.changeValue}" data-value="0" >
        <lightning:icon class="icn_green" iconName="utility:check" size="small" />
    </div>
</aura:if>
<aura:if  isTrue="{!v.account.cel_email_mailable__c!= 'Y' }">
    <div  onclick="{!c.changeValue}" data-value="1">
        <lightning:icon class="icn_red" iconName="utility:close"  size="small" />
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

It passes both conditions and displays both icons, image below : 
[image]

Comment: Check field api name. Lighting attributes are case sensetive.

Comment: I suggest you print the value in {!v.account.cel_email_mailable__c} before your aura:if and see what it returning.

Comment: @Kal how do we do this in a .cmp?

Comment: Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you print the value in `{!v.account.cel_email_mailable__c}` before your `aura:if` and see what it returning. See below. And also, I took the liberty of changing your condition slightly because it felt like you did not know how to use `else` in `aura:if`.

```
<!-- Print the value in your component like so: -->
cel_email_mailable__c = {!v.account.cel_email_mailable__c}

<!-- aura:if with embedded else statement -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.account.cel_email_mailable__c == 'Y'}">
    <div onclick="{!c.changeValue}" data-value="0" >
        <lightning:icon class="icn_green" iconName="utility:check" size="small"/>
    </div>
    <aura:set attribute="else">
        <div onclick="{!c.changeValue}" data-value="1">
            <lightning:icon class="icn_red" iconName="utility:close"  size="small"/>
        </div>
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

Comment: {!v.account.cel_email_mailable__c} is empty i have this result :  (cel_email_mailable__c =                       ) and below the icone close .. , I do not understand why it's empty

Comment: There, you now know the problem. {!v.account.cel_email_mailable__c} is returning a blank value and so is falling into the else block. If your question is why is it blank at all, then that is outside the scope of this question because we have now answered your main question 'Aura if doesn't work'. For troubleshooting, I suggest you use console.log('------> ' + JSON.stringify(component.get('v.account'), null, 2)); in your ControllerJS to see the value in account variable in your browser logs. If that doesn't help, please post a new question with more details and code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Lightning is cAsE sEnSiTiVe. Check the capitalization of your field and attribute name. As an aside, it is far less error prone to simply say == Y and == N, rather than invert the nature of the tests. For example, if the value is == X, then both icons would also show.

---

```
{!v.account.cel_email_mailable__c == 'Y'}
```

and

```
{!v.account.cel_email_mailable__c == 'N'}
```

Comment: I checked the name of the API and the type of the field is text with a character
,when I changed my code with yours, nothing was displayed

Comment: @redacherrabi I don't know what else to tell you; if the condition were met correctly, only one icon should display.

Comment: its good but the problem now is this field cel_email_mailable__c  is blank

Comment: @redacherrabi Check the capitalization of the field name...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the logic.

Aura:if will render both sections with whatever cel_email_mailable__c not equals to N or Y.

For example :

```
cel_email_mailable__c  == NULL 
cel_email_mailable__c  == 'A'
```